# How to access text in respond returned by fetch()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

New to React and javascript. I am studying it now and I tried to get a string from server in React client and display it. My code as below

server.js

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 3001 )

app.use(express.static("ayersapp/build"));

app.get('/message', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello first respond!');
});

app.listen(app.get("port"));
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Message from './message'

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to React</h1>
        </header>
        <p className="App-intro">
          To get started, edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload.
        </p>
        <Message />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

message.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class Message extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {message: "abc"};
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch(`/message`).then(m=>{
            this.setState(
                {message: m.blob()}
            );
        });
    }

    render(){
        const msg = this.state.message;
        return <p>{msg}</p>;
    }
}

export default Message;
```

from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) I can access the string data by using .then(()=>{}). But I got this error

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in p (at message.js:19)
    in Message (at App.js:17)
    in div (at App.js:9)
    in App (at index.js:7)
```

Could anyone let me know how I can access the string in object Promise?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    .then(response => response.text())
    .then(text => {
        console.log('text = ', text)
//             this.setState({
//                  message: text
//             })

     })
```

Comment: @BingLan added a working snippet to demonstrate code is working

Comment: Thanks! Adding a 'return' before response.text() to make it work for me, I got this from https://davidwalsh.name/fetch, any idea why?

Comment: I am using arrow function that return the implicitly while in the linked example he is using regular functions that require explicit return